# How to think about iid observations

Tags: distributions, iid

I'm trying to make sure my understanding of iid observations is rock solid and so I have two write-ups in which I've attempted to accurately explain the concept. Can anyone comment on the accuracy of each of these write-ups?

```
(1) One way to represent a population is through a random variable X, which would have
a pdf/pmf that modeled the relative frequencies of values with the population. If you
were to sample from the population such that each subject is equally likely to be
selected and so that selecting a particular subject has no bearing on the
likelihood of any other subject being selected, then each observation can be thought of
as a realization of the random variable X. As such, we denote the observations x_i.
Under these conditions the observations can be thought of as independent draws from the
random variable X, and so the observations are said to be iid (independently and
identically distributed) – i.e. the observations can be thought of as n realizations of
the random variable X.
```

Or

```
(2) One way to represent a population is through a random variable X, which would have
a pdf/pmf that modeled the relative frequencies of values within the population. If you
were to sample from the population such that each subject is equally likely to be
selected and so that selecting a particular subject has no bearing on the
likelihood of any other subject being selected, then each observation can be thought of
as a realization of the random variable X. As such, we denote the observations x_i.
Under these conditions the observations can be thought of as independent draws from
identically distributed random variables, X_1,…,X_n, where x_i is the realization of
the random variable X_i for all i. Hence, the observations are said to be iid
(independently and identically distributed).
```

There are a couple of portions that I want to get answers about, specifically.

- Could the statement "such that each subject is equally likely to be selected and so that" in the second sentence of each write up be removed without affecting the accuracy of the statement?
- Are both of these ways of thinking about iid draws correct?
- If both statements are correct, is it conventional to interpret the draws as being realizations from one RV, or each observation as a realization from separate but identical RV's?

Comment: Hint: observations do not have a distribution, only random variables do. Hint 2: If all observations came from the same random variable, then this random variable would produce many values "at once". But a random variable is a real-valued _function_, not a _correspondence_.

Comment: Okay, so it is not possible for there to be more than one realization of a random variable. Therefore, each observation is a  realization of a distinct random variable (each of which is identical to but independent from the others). This would be analogous to saying that each observation comes from the same distribution?

Comment: First sentence ok. Second sentence ok. Third sentence: informally yes. But always keep in mind that observations are realizations of random variables. Any other statement should be made w.r.t. to the term "random variable", and not to the term "observation".

Comment: To clarify, is the allusion in your first comment to the observations being produced "at once" absolutely critical to each random variable being iid? It seems as if it would, because if the observations were taken sequentially then the distribution of the population would be modified after each draw (b/c samples are taken without replacement) and so the RVs would not be identical.

Comment: I'm also confused about there being only one realization of a random variable. Isn't a realization of a RV a random variate? And this Wikipedia article for Random Variate implies that multiple of them can be realized from the same random variable.

Comment: To your first question, no it is not -it only leads us to the fact that each observation comes from a distinct random variable. These random variables may be i.i.d or just independent or just identically distributed but not independent. The distribution of the _population_ has nothing to do with how we sample from it, but with these questions you are steadily moving towards a full exposition of the fundamental base of how statistics perceive the world.

Comment: RV's are functions, as any other. So you have $X =g(z)$ (although one rarely knows the functional form of $g(z)$ - it is _not_ the probability density function). Now assume the domain of the RV is $z \in [1,2]$. You can insert $z=1.5$ into the R.V and you will get $g(1.5)$. You can insert $z=1.7$ into the RV and you will get $g(1.7)$. But can you insert $z=1.5$ and $z=1.7$ _together_? Also, if you insert just $z=1.5$ you will get _one_ value out of $g(1.5)$, not more - this is the essence of the concept of a function as apposed to the concept of correspondence.

Comment: @Alecos Papadopoulos thanks for the replies. Regarding sampling methodology, if I randomly picked an observation from a population wouldn't the marginal dist. of the RV representing that draw be the dist. of the population? And if the draw was without replacement, then if I drew a second observation wouldn't it be from a technically different population than the first draw, implying the marginal dist. of the RV representing this draw is also different than the first? I'm still missing how RV's could be considered iid if they represent sequential draws from a population without replacement.

Comment: @Alecos Papadopoulos thanks. I see that the sample space is the domain of a Rv and the range is something like the reals, for example. So I guess it would be informally correct to say that the sample space is the set of possible outcomes from a phenomenon, and a random variable is simply a function that converts these outcomes to real numbers (or some other space). I.e. A RV is essentially just a way to code outcomes numerically.

Comment: To your firt comment, the population is described by a _joint_ , multivariate distribution. Look up the relation between the joint distribution and the marginal distributions of the RV's.

Comment: To your second comment: exactly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11180/discussion-between-tjnel-and-alecos-papadopoulos)